# What seems like a basic C# query, but I'm not a C# developer

Tags: c#

This won't make a lot of sense so apologies in advance, I'm not a C# developer but have been given some code to look at.

I need to pass a model object in to a function, however I looping through and so will need to build the name dynamically. So lets assume I would normally reference it like so.

```
model.employee.title
model.employee.forename
```

How can I reference it using a string for the last part.

I'm using a foreach to loop through the various parts which is fine, but I then need to pass the object in to a function call. I have the name of the last part as a literal string ("title","forname") but I'm not sure how I pass that in.

So effectively what I need is to use something like

```
model.employee."title"
```

or

```
model.employee.varContainingTheName
```

I know these won't work, but have no idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, if you have a string of the member name, you're talking about reflection. The reflection API differs between fields and properties, so you'd need to know which it is, for example (where `obj` is `model.employee`, and `name` is the name of the member you want to access):

```
object value = obj.GetType().GetField(name).GetValue(obj);
```

vs:

```
object value = obj.GetType().GetProperty(name).GetValue(obj, null);
```

Alternatively, use an API like [FastMember](http://nuget.org/packages/FastMember) (which incidentally is much faster than raw reflection - it uses lots of voodoo):

```
var wrapper = ObjectAccessor.Create(obj);
object value = wrapper[name];
```

Comment: @Jodrell the specific voodoo that I *mention* is already linked; if you mean a *more general* voodoo, then you can "download" that from Intel, via snailmail - a few "i7-3770"s should help.

Comment: Will that give me the value? If so that's not what I mean. I need to pass something in to a function, so for example it would be somehtmlfunction(m => m.employee.name) but the name part will be "dynamic". Apologies for the crap explanations but know very little about C# so I would no doubt use the wrong terms.

Answer (score 1):

If you develop the  model.employee class and use it like that, you should consider using [dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xfhwa508.aspx) for fileds.

```
    class employee
    {
        public Dictionary<string, object> properties = new Dictionary<string,object>();

        public employee()
        {
            properties.Add("time", DateTime.Now);
            properties.Add("name", "Bill Gates");
        }
    }
```

and then use it like this:

```
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.properties["time"];
```

this code will be faster and easier to read.

Comment: Thanks, I'm pretty new to C#, we have now moved to a model similar to your suggestion.